# PuTTY cannot open the ppk generated by conversion from PEM using command-line Linux PuTTYgen

Tags: ssh, fedora, putty, amazon-ec2, ppk

Local system: Fedora
Remote system: AWS AMI Linux
SSH client: putty

Problem: Putty using pem to access AWS AMI will result on error.
Error message: OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (old PEM format)
Solution: sudo puttygen pemKey.pem -o ppkKey.ppk -O private
Reference: https://www.puttygen.com/convert-pem-to-ppk

Another problem: putty cannot open the generated ppk
Error message: unable to open file
Solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: open and copy the generated ppk, then paste on text editor, saved as ppk.
Reference: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=864887